# Redis EXPIRE: Is there a practical upper bound on the number of seconds?

Tags: redis

We are using Redis (actually ElastiCache) to store records with a TTL, using the EXPIRE command. Some of them have an expiration 3 months in the future, and we have observed that some of them don't expire. My question is, is there a best practice for expiring records, e.g., no more than 24 hours in the future? Or, is EXPIREAT more reliable?

Comment: What do you mean by "don't expire"? As described [here](https://redis.io/commands/expire#how-redis-expires-keys) expired keys are not immediately deleted, but they should be if you try to access them.

Comment: Did you try TTL/PTTL commands on those keys?

Comment: Anyway, FWIW in Redis vanilla, there's no practical upper bound to TTLs